# Why does make not recompile these object files when the source files are changed?

Tags: makefile, fortran, gnu-make, gfortran

I have two sources files, `library.f90` and `toolbox.f90` in a separate directory. These are compiled into object files, which are linked when compiling the main file, aptly called `main`. Initially, I had this Makefile:

```
TARGET  = main
SRC     = ${TARGET}.f95

FC      = /usr/bin/gfortran
CFLAGS  = -O2 -std=gnu -Wfatal-errors -I${INCLUDE}

INCLUDE = /home/ma/include
OBJ     = library.o toolbox.o
OBJ_SRC = $(subst .o,.f90,${OBJ})


all: ${TARGET}

${TARGET}: ${SRC} ${OBJ}
    @${FC} ${CFLAGS} -pedantic -Wall ${OBJ} ${SRC} -o ${TARGET}

${OBJ}:
    @echo "Compiling $(subst .o,,$@)"
    @${FC} ${CFLAGS} -c ${INCLUDE}/$(subst .o,.f90,$@) -o $@

clean:
    @rm -vf ${TARGET} ${OBJ}
```

but this doesn't recompile `library.o` (or `toolbox.o`, respectively) when the source file `library.f90` or `toolbox.f90` is edited. I figured this was because the dependency was missing, so I tweaked the Makefile to look like this:

```
TARGET  = main
SRC     = ${TARGET}.f95

FC      = /usr/bin/gfortran
CFLAGS  = -O2 -std=gnu -Wfatal-errors -I${INCLUDE}

INCLUDE = /home/ma/include
OBJ     = library.o toolbox.o

all: ${TARGET}

${TARGET}: ${SRC} ${OBJ}
    @${FC} ${CFLAGS} -pedantic -Wall ${OBJ} ${SRC} -o ${TARGET}

${OBJ}: ${OBJ_SRC}
    @echo "Compiling $(subst .o,,$@)"
    @${FC} ${CFLAGS} -c ${INCLUDE}/$(subst .o,.f90,$@) -o $@

clean:
    @rm -vf ${TARGET} ${OBJ}
```

This, however, throws the error

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'library.f90', needed by 'library.o'.  Stop.
```

I don't understand this, because there isn't a rule to build `${SRC}` either, but make recognizes the dependency there and compiles the source file as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first version, the object files' rule did not specify any prerequisite. That's why make did not check whether `library.f90` had changed, and therefore did not recreate it.

Your second version is slightly better, but it now means that both `library.o` and `toolbox.o` depend on **both** `library.f90` and `toolbox.f90`, meaning that if either one is changed, both are rebuild, and if either one is missing, both builds will fail.

As for why your rule failed: It was looking for `library.f90` in your current directory, but from the rule I deduce that the sources are in the subdirectory `/home/ma/include`.

A better solution would be this:

```
${OBJ} : %.o : ${INCLUDE}/%.f90
        ${FC} ${CFLAGS} -c $^ -o $@
```

(I also removed the leading `@`, as I find it very useful to see the actual command it's trying to run.)